# DataType is changing in Avro file with ExecuteSQL processor in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, avro, avro-tools

I am trying to generate Avro file from SQL Server using ExecuteSQL processor. Generated Avro file is converting date, datetime, varchar datatypes to string datatype.Sample :

> {"name":"Date","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"WeekBegin","type":["null","string"]}

Could anyone please suggest  some solution to this.

The executeSQL processor configuration is as follow:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the sql create statement for the table so we can see the database columns and types?

Comment: Hi Bryan, Thanks for the response. Please find the DDL : CREATE TABLE dev.test_table (
 date DATE, weekbegin DATETIME
);

Comment: Ok generally the two reasons this could happen are if you have "Use Logical Types" false, then date and datetime would be strings, or if the JDBC driver returns something wrong/unusual for the column type, like if it says type is "other" then NiFi just goes to a string.

Comment: The code is here if you are interested: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-extension-utils/nifi-database-utils/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/util/db/JdbcCommon.java#L476-L631

Comment: I tried "Use Logical Types" as true where date and timestamp are being converted to **date** and **timestamp-millis** respectively. My ultimate goal is to load this Avro file data to Redshift through copy command where all rows are displaying _NULL_ values.

Comment: ok so "Use Logical Type" did produce the correct types in the schema then right?

Comment: "Use Logical Type" did prouce date, but timestamp came as **timestamp-millis**. My Redshift DDL : CREATE TABLE dev.test_table (
 date date,
 weekbegin timestamp
 );
Datatypes supported by Redshift are available in this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html which doesn't contain **timestamp-millis**. So is there any way to define these data types while Avro is generated? Because of this datatype mismatch data is being inserted as _NULL_ in the Redshift table.

Comment: I even tried to follow this post : https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Convert-Json-to-Avro-processor-Failed-to-Parse-Record-Schema/td-p/171121 to convert the json file to Avro format using **ConvertJsonToAvro** processor, but I wasn't able to parse the **Record Shema**.

Comment: Your original question was about how to get the correct schema coming out of ExecuteSQL so that it wasn't using String for those two columns, and that has been answered by using "Use Logical Types". The question of how to make that lineup with Redshift is a completely different question.